# Soft keyboard covers text edit box... usual fixes do not work

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I know there has been several posts regarding this issue, but I went through several pages of google results and haven't found an answer that works in my situation (surprisingly enough).

Before you give me the common answers... I've tried changing the manifest to

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and just about every combination of options available... none is sufficient for what I want.  "adjustResize" moves everything at the bottom of my activity up... which isn't effective because I have more things below the edit text, and "adjustPan" does nothing.

I also tried adding a scroll view, but that didn't solve the issue either.  Yes, I could scroll to see the edittext with the keyboard open, but that isn't user friendly.

I would be happy with either one of these two solutions:

1. Have the softkeyboard align perfectly below the edittext box that I am currently using (ideal solution) or
2. Have the softkeyboard act as it does in landscape mode and fill the whole screen while allowing for me to see the text I'm typing.

Here is my xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/ccap_logo" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/login_lastname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtLastName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLastName"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtLastName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:text="@string/login_email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/login_submit"
        android:onClick="submitOnClick" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/login_trouble"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="emailCCAP"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your activity set to launch in fullScreen mode. adjustPan | adjustResize do not work in fullScreen mode.